# google maps waypoints issue

Tags: google-maps, routes

I have a input form that allows user to create a route with start, stop and 8 waypoints. Everything works ok but my problem is that all the inputs have to be filled out for the route to be rendered. I dont know how to fix this issue so that the user could enter only:

1. Start and End points, or
2. Start and End points and Waypoints ( as many as they need, not more than 8, to create the route ).

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="map_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var stop1 = document.getElementById("stop1").value;
    var stop2 = document.getElementById("stop2").value;
    var stop3 = document.getElementById("stop3").value;
    var stop4 = document.getElementById("stop4").value;
    var stop5 = document.getElementById("stop5").value;
    var stop6 = document.getElementById("stop6").value;
    var stop7 = document.getElementById("stop7").value;
    var stop8 = document.getElementById("stop8").value;
    var waypts= [{ location: stop1 }, { location: stop2 }, { location: stop3 },  { location: stop4 },  { location: stop5 },  { location: stop6 },  { location: stop7 },  { location: stop8 }];


    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
        }
      }
    });
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
<div style="margin:20px;border-width:2px;">

<label for="start">Start :</label>
  <input type="text" id="start" name="start" /><br /><br />

<i>Add multiple Stops along the route (Optional)</i> <br /><br />
<label for="stop1">Stop 1 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop1" name="stop1" /><br />
<label for="stop2">Stop 2 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop2" name="stop2" /><br />
<label for="stop3">Stop 3 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop3" name="stop3" /><br />
<label for="stop4">Stop 4 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop4" name="stop4" /><br />
<label for="stop4">Stop 5 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop5" name="stop5" /><br />
<label for="stop6">Stop 6 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop6" name="stop6" /><br />
<label for="stop7">Stop 7 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop7" name="stop7" /><br />
<label for="stop8">Stop 8 :</label>
  <input type="text" id="stop8" name="stop8" /><br /><br />


<label for="end">Stop :</label>
  <input type="text" id="end" name="end" /><br />
<br />
  <input type="submit" value="Create Route" onclick="calcRoute();">
 </div>
 <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you post your map_style.css file - takes some extra effort to reproduce what you are doing without it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for empty fields and duplicate the value of the previous field there. When it is rendered you will have a number of waypoints on top of each other, but I suspect you can't see that. This is probably the method that needs the least change to your code. More extensive changes would make the form dynamic, adding more fields as the user fills it out.

The following code snippet seems to be close to what you want... I tested it with one and two waypoints, and it behaved itself. I still wasn't able to get the map to render - but I believe that is due to a different problem, related to the .css file (formatting got a bit mangled in your comment...)

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;    
    var waypts = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii< 8; ii++) {      
        var thisStop = document.getElementById("stop" + (ii+1)).value;
        if (thisStop.length > 0) {
            waypts[ii] = {location: thisStop};
        }
    }
```

// next few lines are deleted; pick it up again from:

```
var request = {
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really understand what you are saying. i'm just learning google maps. Could you be more specific? Thank you

Comment: is it supposed to be something like this: `code` for(var i = 0; i < waypts.length; i++)`code` ?

Comment: thank you very much for your response. Here is my map_style.css: `code`html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
`code`

Comment: do i have to modify something else? At this point i can select start and end points and first waypoint to create a route, the other waypoints dont work.

Comment: Try it again - changed the `if` statement code slightly. I think it's now good.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked perfectly. you are amazing. One more question though: how would i save the route in a mysql database? I dont expect you to write the code fom me but just a suggestion on how would i approach that point. Thank you a million times.

Comment: Glad it worked. Since the route is an object of variable size, it would probably be best to use JSON to encode it into a string that you can store in the database. See for example http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSON-example.php . If my code answers your question, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the little check mark...